# How do I test for DOM changes created by a setInterval function when using Jest/React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, tdd, react-testing-library

I created a simple countdown component that I would like to test is working correctly with React testing library. Everything works as expected in a browser but when testing the rendered output never advances more than one second regardless of the values used.

Component (custom hook based on [Dan Abramovs blog post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import TimerButton from "../TimerButton/TimerButton"

// custom hook
function useInterval(callback, delay, state) {
  const savedCallback = useRef()

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current()
    }
    if (state.isOn) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [state])
}

const Timer = () => {
  const initialState = {
    minutes: 25,
    seconds: 0,
    isOn: false,
  }
  const [timerData, setTimerData] = useState(initialState)

  useInterval(
    () => {
      if (timerData.seconds === 0) {
        if (timerData.minutes === 0) {
          setTimerData({ ...timerData, isOn: false })
        } else {
          setTimerData({
            ...timerData,
            minutes: timerData.minutes - 1,
            seconds: 59,
          })
        }
      } else {
        setTimerData({ ...timerData, seconds: timerData.seconds - 1 })
      }
    },
    1000,
    timerData,
  )

  const displayedTime = `${
    timerData.minutes >= 10 ? timerData.minutes : `0${timerData.minutes}`
  }:${timerData.seconds >= 10 ? timerData.seconds : `0${timerData.seconds}`}`

  const startTimer = () => {
    setTimerData({ ...timerData, isOn: true })
  }

  const stopTimer = () => {
    setTimerData({ ...timerData, isOn: false })
  }

  const resetTimer = () => {
    setTimerData(initialState)
  }

  return (
    <div className="timer__container" data-testid="timerContainer">
      <div className="timer__time-display" data-testid="timeDisplayContainer">
        {displayedTime}
      </div>
      <div className="timer__button-wrap">
        <TimerButton buttonAction={startTimer} buttonValue="Start" />
        <TimerButton buttonAction={stopTimer} buttonValue="Stop" />
        <TimerButton buttonAction={resetTimer} buttonValue="Reset" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Timer
```

And the test (there is a `beforeEach` and `afterEach` calling `jest.useFakeTimers()` and `jest.useRealTimers()` respectively above):

```
  it("Assert timer counts down by correct interval when starting timer", async () => {
    render(<Timer />)
    const initialTime = screen.getByText("25:00")
    const startTimerButton = screen.getByText("Start")

    expect(initialTime).toBeInTheDocument() // This works fine

    fireEvent.click(startTimerButton)
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000)
    })

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("24:55")).toBeInTheDocument())
  })
```

Output of the test:

```
    Unable to find an element with the text: 24:55. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="timer__container"
          data-testid="timerContainer"
        >
          <div
            class="timer__time-display"
            data-testid="timeDisplayContainer"
          >
            24:59 <--- This value is always the same 
          </div>
          <div
            class="timer__button-wrap"
          >
          { ... }
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Id like to assert that the correct time is being displayed after moving the time forward by different increments, if I can do this then it will allow for a much more comprehensive set of tests.

I have tried using many of the timing methods in Jest including advanceTimersByTime(), runOnlyPendingTimers(), runAllTimers() to no avail, I can never get the time to advance by more than 1 second. I have also added `console.log()`s in at various points in the `useInterval` function and can verify that the function is being called a varying number of times depending on how much I try to advance the time by (it gets called numbers of seconds + 1 times as expected).

When logging out the state data I have seen that the `timerData` state does not update except for the last run through:

```
callback {"minutes":25,"seconds":0,"isOn":true} // Every time but the last

callback {"minutes":24,"seconds":59,"isOn":true} // The last time only
```

Im thinking it must be something to do with how Im referencing the state values during update, or how Jests fake timers interact with state updates though I really dont know at this point

Comment: Why do you define the custom hook _inside_ the component?! That means it gets redefined on every render.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Have moved the hook out of the component and edited post, behaviour still unchanged. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of playing and trying many different methods I have a solution for this.

Further investigation into the calling of the useInterval() function called showed that:

- the correct lines to update state were being reached, but the component was only re-rendering once after all these loops of the setInterval function despite the number of updates to state that were supposedly triggered (verified using console logs)
- altering the time passed to setInterval (`i`) to be less than 500ms showed that the time was advancing by amounts roughly equivalent to `1 % i`
- the component only re-renders once for each tick of the setInterval function that occurs under the time passed to `jest.advanceTimersByTime()`

From this it appears that for each call of `jest.advanceTimersByTime()` only one iteration of the setInterval function can be moved through, and so the only way I found to move the interval forward by the correct amount of time is to call advanceTimersByTime() repeatedly via a helper function:

```
const advanceJestTimersByTime = (increment, iterations) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(increment)
    })
  }
}
```

Test updated to:

```
it("Assert timer counts down by correct interval when starting timer", async () => {
  render(<Timer />)

  const initialTime = screen.getByText("25:00")
  const startTimerButton = screen.getByText("Start")

  expect(initialTime).toBeInTheDocument()

  fireEvent.click(startTimerButton)

  advanceJestTimersByTime(1000, 60)

  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("24:00")).toBeInTheDocument())
})
```

This passes and allows for assertions to be made at any point for the countdown